# How to specify year range in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called salaries that have yearID as a column. I would like to specify the range of the year from 2010 to 2014. How could I do that in r ?
I have tried this

```
df <- Salaries(yearID=c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014))
```

also,

```
salar09-05<-Salaries(yearID=c(2010:2014))
```

and

```
sqldf("select * from salaries where yearID > 2009 and date < 2015")
```

neither one of them work.

Comment: Did you meant `data.frame(yearID=c(2010,..`.  Just do `subset(Salaries, yearID %in% 2010:2014)`

Comment: yes, but I already used that in first code where my data frame is Salaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use square brackets to subset.

```
df <- Salaries[Salaries$yearID %in% c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014), ]
```

or

```
df <- Salaries[Salaries$yearID >= 2010 & Salaries$yearID <=2014, ]
```

A single "=" is an assignment operator, not a test of equality.

Comment: you would need Salaries$yearID

Comment: I get this error with all codes I have run: Error in `[.data.frame`(Salaries, yearID >= 2010 & yearID <= 2014, ) : 
  object 'yearID' not found

Comment: Fixed code. Needed to tell R where to find yearID

Comment: This one worked well for me : df <- Salaries[Salaries$yearID >= 2010 & Salaries$yearID <=2014, ]

Answer (score 2):

We can use `subset` with `%in%`

```
subset(Salaries, yearID %in% 2010:2014)
```